# Test usb booting capabilities with qemu under linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, usb-boot

I am running Ubuntu Oneiric and just installed `quemu` to test if my usb device is bootable, because for some reasons, on my laptop the usb boots but on my desktop pc it shows `Boot Erro`

So, does anybody knows how to test with quemu the booting capabilities of my StoreJet usb HDD ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the answer, but can it be improved?

`lsusb`

> Bus ***001*** Device ***007***: ID 152d:2329 JMicron Technology Corp. / JMicron
>   USA Technology Corp. JM20329 SATA Bridge

`sudo qemu-system-x86_64 -m 512 -enable-kvm -usb -device usb-host,hostbus=1,hostaddr=7`

Answer (score 3):

There is also this format that works:

> sudo qemu-system-x86_64 -enable-kvm -m 256 -usb /dev/sdX

It's a bit nicer since you don't have to look up the device numbers.

Answer (score 2):

The `-usbdevice host:bus.addr` flag is the right way to do this now.
For example:

```
sudo qemu-system-x86_64 -enable-kvm -m 256 -usbdevice host:3.6
```

The root privileges (from sudo) are needed to access the usb device node (/dev/bus/usb/003/006 in this case). Without proper permissions or privileges, you will receive permission denied errors, and qemu will not see your device.